# callback does not invoke

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

MongoClient.connect's callback does not invoke

I try to invoke the callback in aws lambda but it doesn't work, however if I remove exports.lambdaHandler and just invoke it by node app.js it works just fine.

```
exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
try {
    MongoClient.connect(url, {
        useNewUrlParser: true
    }, (err, client) => {
        console.log("Connected successfully to server");
    });
    response = {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': JSON.stringify({
            message: 'test'
        })
    }
    return response
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return err;
}
};
```

should return

Connected successfully to server

edit

I changed it to await instead. now it's good

```
exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
try {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(url, {
        useNewUrlParser: true
    })
    const db = client.db(dbName)

    await db.createCollection(collectionName)

    client.close()

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': JSON.stringify({
            message: 'test'
        })
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return err;
}
};
```

Comment: What does it return?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it would return the results else throw an error which will be caught below and returned by Lambda

```js
exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {

    try {
        MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true}, (err, client) => {
            if (err) { console.log(err); throw(err); }
            else { 
               console.log("Connected successfully to server"); 
               console.log(client); 
                response = {
                    'statusCode': 200,
                    'body': JSON.stringify({message: client})
                    };
                return response;
            };
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    }

};
```